# Why doesn't Linux shutdown cleanly?

Tags: linux, shutdown, laptop

I'm running Linux Mint with LXDE on Dell Inspiron 1501.  Whenever I issue `poweroff` command, or reboot or shutdown the computer via the graphical menus, it doesn't seem like a clean shutdown.  In particular, on the next start, Firefox shows the annoying "This is embarrassing" message, and LibreOffice starts the "document recovery" process.

How do I investigate this problem?

Comment: The title of this question is misleading, because none of the symptoms suggest the OS hasn't been shut down cleanly. It simply indicates there are some applications, which did not get shut down cleanly. The question should be reformulated to ask about those applications rather than the OS.

Comment: Close Firefox and LibreOffice and make sure (`ps`) they are really closed before shutting down the machine.

Comment: It's not due to just the applications, not when it's every application I run.  And when these applications are well-known and well-tested.  And when it eats the files on the Windows filesystem as well.  And the suggestion to close the programs manually is ridiculous.  It's the computer's job to do mundane tasks.